# Continuous Image of $S^{n-1}$ in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Let $f:S^{n-1}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a nonconstant continuous function.

1. $S^{n-1}$ is Compact & Connected$\implies$ Its image is of the form $[a,b]$ in $\mathbb{R}$.
2. For any $c \in (a,b)$: $\#\{f^{-1}(c)\}>1$. 
   If not, then $f:S^{n-1}\setminus \{f^{-1}(c)\}\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and since $S^{n-1}\setminus \{f^{-1}(c)\}$ is connected it image i.e $[a,c)\cup(c,b]$ is connected. Contradiction.
3. There exist $x \in S^{n-1}$ such that $f(x)=f(-x)$ 
   Consider $g(x)=f(x)-f(-x) \implies g$ is an odd function. If $g(x)=0$ then we are done. If not, as $g(S^{n-1})$ is connected, either $g(x)>0$ or $g(x)<0$ for all $x \in S^{n-1}$. Contradicting the fact that $g$ is odd.

Geometrically I can see that:

1. In $S^1$ for every $c \in (a,b)$: $\{f^{-1}(c)\}$ has atleast two points.
2. In $S^2$ for every $c \in (a,b)$: $\{f^{-1}(c)\}$ should atleast contain a shape of homeomorphic to a circle i.e $S^1$ (**Is this true?**)

**My Question:** Can we tell that in $S^{n-1}(n\ge3)$ for every $c \in (a,b)$: $\{f^{-1}(c)\}$ contains a set homeomorphic to $S^{n-2}$?

Comment: Minor note: In point 1, you can't conclude that the image is of the form $[a, b]$ just from compactness. You are also using the fact that $S^1$ is connected.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani: Thank you for pointing it out. I have edited it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **My Question:** Can we tell that in $S^{n-1}(n\ge3)$ for every $c \in (a,b)$: $\{f^{-1}(c)\}$ contains a set homeomorphic to $S^{n-2}$?

No.

Consider any closed subset $A\subseteq S^{n-1}$ such that $A$ disconnects the sphere into two nonempty open components $U_1,U_2$. Since $S^{n-1}$ is perfectly normal then we can construct $f:S^{n-1}\to [-1,1]$ such that $f^{-1}(0)=A$ and $f^{-1}(-1)$ is a singleton in $U_1$ while $f^{-1}(1)$ is a singleton in $U_2$.

All we need to have now is a subset $A\subseteq S^{n-1}$ that is closed, disconnects the sphere but it does not contain a copy of $S^{n-2}$. For $n=3$ this can be simply done by taking [the (closed) topologist's sine curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve) around $S^{2}$. This then can be lifted to higher dimensions.

Comment: Dang! This disconnecting curve is very close to being a loop; I wonder, can the conjecture be salvaged by requiring $f$ to be smooth?

Comment: @Karl We can always separate closed subsets by a smooth function: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/963209/finding-bump-function-on-a-smooth-manifold-using-partitions-of-unity But my $f$ above is actually a glueing of two such "separations". Glueing of smooth functions is not necessarily smooth, but I think we can construct our separation functions in such a way that the glueing actually is smooth (by requiring the derivative to be trivial over $A$). But I'm not sure.